# Properties of the operator $T_f(g) := f\cdot g$.

Tags: functional-analysis

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Let $T_f: C_c(\R^n)\subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \to L^2(\R^n)$; $g \mapsto f\cdot g$ where $f \in C(\R^n)$. I want to show that if $\|T_f\|< \infty$ then $f \in C_b(\R^n)$.

I tried to do this by contradiction: Assume that $f$ is not bounded. Find $x_0 \in \R^n$ s.t. $|f(x)| > \|T_f\| +1$ for all $x \in J$ where $J = [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ for some $\delta > 0$, which exists by continuity of $f$. Now I want to find a $g \in C_c(\R^n)$ s.t. $\|g\|_2 \leq 1$ and
$$
 \| fg \|_2 = \left ( \int_{\R^n} |fg|^2 \right)^{1/2} \geq ( \|T_f\| +1) \left( \int_{\operatorname{supp}(g)} |g|^2 \right)^{1/2} > \|T_f\|
$$ So I want $g \in C_c(\R^n), \ J \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(g), \ \|g\|_2 = 1$. How can I find such a $g$ ?

Comment: Maybe you can look for a *sequence* $\{g_k\}_k$ of continuous functions with compact support in $J$ such that $\|g_k\|_2 \to 1$. You could approximate $\chi_J$ this way.

Comment: Try making $g$ look like a tall bump.

Answer (score 1):

The function

$$h(x) := \begin{cases} \exp \left( \frac{1}{1-x^2} \right) & |x| \leq 1 \\ 0 & |x|>1 \end{cases}$$

is continuous (actually even smooth) and its support equals $B[0,1]$. Hints:

1. Modify $h$ such that $\text{supp} \, h = B[0,\delta]$.
2. Modify $h$ such that $\text{supp} \, h = B[x_0,\delta]$.
3. Apply a proper scaling such that $\|h\|_2 = 1$.